# Hackerrank All Women's Codesprint 2019: Visually Balanced Sections

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

Link: https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/hackerrank-all-womens-codesprint-2019/challenges/visually-balanced-sections/problem

## Problem Description

> A rack has \$n\$ horizontal compartments. The leftmost compartment is the \$1^{st}\$ compartment and the rightmost compartment is the \$n^{th}\$ compartment. Each of the compartments of a rack has a colorful item. A section of a rack consists of one or more consecutive compartments.
>   [image]
>
> A section (\$i^{th}\$ compartment to \$j^{th}\$ compartment where, \$i \le j\$) of a rack is visually balanced if the items within the section can be re-arranged in such a way that the color sequence of the items from the \$i^{th}\$ compartment to the \$j^{th}\$ compartment is same as the color sequence of the items from the \$j^{th}\$ compartment to the \$i^{th}\$ compartment.
>
> Few examples of visually balanced sections are:
>   [image]
>   [image]
>   [image]
>
> Note that, in the third example, the items in this section can be re-arranged in such a way that the color sequence of the items from the \$1^{st}\$ compartment of this section to the compartment of this section will be same as the color sequence of the items from the compartment of this section to the \$1^{st}\$ compartment of this section.
>
> Given the colors of each of the \$n\$ items of a rack, your task is to determine the number of visually balanced sections of a rack.
>
> #### Function Description
>
> Complete the *visuallyBalancedSections* function in the editor below. It should return an integer denoting the number of visually balanced sections of a rack..
>
> *visuallyBalancedSections* has the following parameter(s):
>
> colors: an integer array representing the colors of item in each compartment
>
> #### Input Format
>
> - The first line contains a single integer \$t\$ denoting the number of scenarios.
> - The first line of each scenario contains a single integer \$n\$ denoting the number of compartments of a rack.
> - Each of the next line \$i\$ of the \$n\$ subsequent lines (where \$1 \le i \le n\$) of a scenario contains an integer \$color\$ denoting the color of the item in the \$i^{th}\$ compartment.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> - \$1 \le t \le 100\$
> - \$1 \le n \le 1000\$
> - \$1 \le color \le 50\$
>
> #### Output Format
>
> - For each scenario, print an integer denoting the number of visually balanced sections of a rack.
>
> #### Sample Input 0
>
> ```
> 1
> 4
> 1
> 2
> 1
> 2
> ```
>
> #### Sample Output 0
>
> ```
> 7
> ```
>
> #### Explanation 0
>
> There is only one scenario where the rack has four compartments.
>
> - The \$1^{st}\$ compartment has an item of \$= 1\$.
> - The \$2^{nd}\$ compartment has an item of \$= 2\$.
> - The \$3^{rd}\$ compartment has an item of \$= 1\$.
> - The \$4^{th}\$ compartment has an item of \$= 2\$.
>
> The visually balanced sections are:
>
> 1. {\$\{1\}\$} - compartment 1
> 2. {\$\{2\}\$} - compartment 2
> 3. {\$\{1\}\$} - compartment 3
> 4. {\$\{2\}\$} - compartment 4
> 5. {\$\{1, 2, 1\}\$} - compartments 1, 2 and 3
> 6. {\$\{2, 1, 2\}\$} - compartments 2, 3 and 4
> 7. {\$\{1, 2, 1, 2\}\$} - compartments 1, 2, 3 and 4

---

This current solution times out. I have an idea for a faster solution with memoisation, but I'm still working on it so I decided to submit this for review in the interim.

### Current Solution

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from copy import copy

def is_palindrome(counter):
    return len(list(filter(lambda x: x%2, counter.values()))) == (1 if sum(counter.values()) % 2 else 0)

def visuallyBalancedSections(colours):
    counter = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    total = 0
    for i, val in enumerate(colours):
        counter[val] += 1
        temp_counter = copy(counter)
        for j in range(i+1):
            total += int(is_palindrome(temp_counter))
            temp_counter[colours[j]] -= 1
    return total
```

Comment: In future code, I would probably not alias it, but I had already written the code in this answer by the time you guys made your comment (uploading came much later because formatting the question is stressful).

Comment: All that explanation really boils down to "*compute the number of (possibly overlapping) substrings that are permutations of palindromes*", doesn't it?  I think that reproducing the problem statement word-for-word really isn't a good use of your time and effort.

Comment: I thought it would be better to produce the original rather than my interpretation of it, as it is possible I may misunderstand something, and reading the original may give prospective reviewers access to some key insight. But I'll consider your suggestion going forward.